# CMakeList.txt -X -lm options VALA GLib.Math

Tags: cmake, gtk, vala

I am compiling a project in Vala and GTK +... In the compiler I pass options "-X -lm" corresponding to GLib.Math.

I'm already using glib-2.0 package but not know to spend those options through the  CMakeList.txt file.

currently I run the following command to compile:
$ valac --pkg glib-2.0 main.vala -X -lm -o app

everything perfect, but not know how to make CMakeList.txt compile with these options "-X -lm"

Somebody give me a hand with this? Thousand thanks!

PS: Sorry for my bad English

SOLUTION:
add following line or modify if exist:

link_libraries(${DEPS_LIBRARIES} -lm)

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to pass `-X -lm` to valac—when using a build system like CMake or autotools, typically the build system first converts the Vala code to C (`valac -C`), then hooks into the existing architecture for compiling the C.  What you want to do is tell CMake to link to libm, which you probably want to use [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) for.  Something like `target_link_libraries(target_name m)`.

Comment: Thanks, It did not help me what you said... thing i did was add the following line (or modify if exist): link_libraries(${DEPS_LIBRARIES} -lm)